# Can we install the Hindi fonts in Android 2.2?

Tags: android

I am unable to view Hindi fonts in my Android mobile. Right now its showing square boxes.
Can we install the Hindi(devnagari) fonts in Android 2.2?

Comment: You need it in particular application or for whole device apps?

Comment: I need it for web browser only. ao that i can view hindi fots website as well currentlly its showing square boxes

Comment: Are you developing that web site,? Because if you are just worried about viewing 3rd party web site, Most advanced browsers including Android's should be able to display UTF..

Comment: Use opera browser. It handles fonts on its server. I think it will display Hindi too.

Comment: i m using opera, its also showing square boxes.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no support for hindi &  tamil fonts on Android. Read [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=507) issue reported at google. Read all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to read Hindi on your android phone, you can visit [Original Tips](http://www.originaltips.com/133-how-to-install-devanagari-hindi-and-marathi-fonts-unicode-in-android-mobile-phones-and-tablets).